# Sending mail from unix with attachment

Tags: unix

I have a file with pipe delimiters. I'd like to replace the pipes with `<tab>` and mail the file as attachment. I do get mail but still with pipes.

Part of my script -

> OUTPUT_FILE=/path/to/file/filename.xls
>
> sed 's/|/       /g' $OUTPUT_FILE
>
> uuencode ${OUTPUT_FILE} $OUTPUT_FILE | mail -s "Test"  test@xyz.com

I tried replacing $OUTPUT_FILE with ${OUTPUT_FILE} in sed but still I get file with pipe.

Comment: Checkout heirloom mailx (previously known as nail) which supports attachments out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Your sed command is not modifying the contents of the file.  You should pipe the output of sed directly to uuencode, like this:

```
OUTPUT_FILE=/path/to/file/filename.xls

sed 's/|/ /g' $OUTPUT_FILE |uuencode ${OUTPUT_FILE} | mail -s "Test" test@xyz.com
```